# How can I enable left click drag or right click in swt.browser

Tags: java, swt

I am trying to embed a web browser inside a java application. 
Unfortunately it has to be in the application and not open a browser.

I have found [org.eclipse.swt.browser](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fbrowser%2FBrowser.html). I am using this browser to display 3D models and when I click in the browser and drag my mouse I should be able to rotate it. Is there an option to enable this or anything I can do to fix this?

You can use this site for an example: 
https://a360.autodesk.com/viewer

When you open the site there are models that can be rotated with left click or moved with right click. [image: Example site]

But when I open the same page using swt.browser I can't neither rotate or drag the model.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;


public class BrowserClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("Browser Example");
    shell.setSize(1300, 800);


    final Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
    browser.setBounds(5, 5, 1275, 750);

    shell.open();
    browser.setUrl("https://a360.autodesk.com/viewer");
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```

[image]

I have attempted removing display.sleep() and I have tried using setTouchEnabled(true) but I can only use it on shell and browser. The display always has it set to false could the issue be here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `SWT.NONE` as the style of the `Browser` on Windows will use Internet Explorer as default. It looks like IE doesn't support whatever magic is used to show the animation.

Try using `SWT.MOZILLA` to force SWT to use XULRunner as a backend.

Here's some more information on how to do that:

[How do I explicitly use Mozilla as the Browser's underlying renderer?](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#howusemozilla)

Comment: I have a custom model viewer that works on my IE normally. Does that mean that it should work just fine in the swt.browser even when it has SWT.NONE

Comment: Does that page you pointed to in your question work for you in IE? It doesn't for me. [This section of the SWT FAQ](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browsernativeie) lists some issues with IE. As an example for SWT < 3.7 IE7 is the newest IE version you'd get in a `Browser` widget. Which version of SWT are you using?

Comment: The site doesn't work in my IE but I have a viewer that I have developed that works in IE just fine I can't really share the viewer unfortunately. 
I tried using jxBrowser and it works fine in that but its not free so I am exploring different options swt.browser being one of them.

Comment: @InsaneCricket Can't really help you beyond this point unfortunately. You could give XULRunner a go, just to make sure that it's not IE withing the `Browser` that keeps it from working. Other than that, have you tried to see if DND works ok on other websites with your browser instance?

Comment: For some reason I keep getting `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.eclipse.swt.internal.mozilla.init.XPCOMInit.GREVersionRange_sizeof()I`
I downloaded it and did this xulrunner.exe --register-global am I missing something?